# No underlining and linebreak

Tags: line-breaking

I was inspired and defined “fillIn” for my purposes with an underline. The problem was that there was no line break.
Then I defined a command “showTextOrLines” that uses the working command “drawLins”. This switches between lines and text. If the text is to be underlined, there is no line break.

```
\newcommand{\showTextOrLines}[3][2]{% Switches between Text 1 and Text 2 
\iftoggle{showAnswers}{\begin{spacing}{#1}#3\end{spacing}}{\drawLins[#1]{#2}} }
```

works,

```
\newcommand{\showTextOrLines}[3][2]{% Switches between Text 1 and Text 2
 \iftoggle{showAnswers}{\begin{spacing}{#1}\underline{#3}\end{spacing}}{\drawLins[#1]{#2}}
 }
```

does not work.

I tried to make a minipage to adjust the size of the empty box in #2 instead of drawLins, worked very well until i tried to underline. No linebreake anymore.
What is wrong?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{mdframed} % für Boxen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\setmainfont{Futura Book BT}[ItalicFont = Futura Book Italic BT,BoldFont = Futura Heavy BT,BoldItalicFont = Futura Heavy Italic BT ]
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fp}%für Rechungen mit Variablen
\usepackage{ulem} %für alle möglichen Unterstreichungen usw
\usepackage{seqsplit} %für Zeilenumbrüche in Umgebungen, hat nicht funktioniert
\usepackage{soul} %für Zeilenumbrüche bei Unterstrichen
\usepackage{forloop}%Für Schleifen


\newtoggle{showComments} %Schalter zum Anzeigen von Kommentaren \mycomment
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{
    \iftoggle{showComments}
    {#1}
    {}
}

\newtoggle{showAnswers}

\newlength{\mylen}

\newcommand{\fillin}[1]{
    \settowidth{\mylen}{#1}
    \iftoggle{showAnswers}
    {#1}
    {\rule{1.5\mylen}{0pt}}
}

\newcommand{\fillinU}[1]{
    \settowidth{\mylen}{#1}
    \iftoggle{showAnswers}
    {\underline{#1}}
    {\underline{\rule{1.5\mylen}{0pt}}}
}


\newcommand{\drawLins}[2][2]{%zeichnet Linien
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2} {%
        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\\[#1\baselineskip]%
    }%
    \typeout{%
        \string\drawLins\space Optionen:%
        1. Argument (optional): Zeilenabstand (Standardwert: 2)
        2. Argument (obligatorisch): Anzahl der zu zeichnenden Linien
    }%
}

\newcommand{\showText}[2]{%Wechselt zwischen Text 1 und TExt 2
    \iftoggle{showAnswers}{#2}{#1}
}%

\newcommand{\showTextOrLines}[3][2]{% Wechselt zwischen Linen (#2) und Text (#3)
    \iftoggle{showAnswers}{\begin{spacing}{#1}\underline{#3}\end{spacing}}{\drawLins[#1]{#2}}
    \typeout{%
        \string\drawLins\space Optionen:%
        1. Argument (optional): Zeilenabstand
        2. Argument (obligatorisch): Text, auf den umgeschaltet werden kann
        3. Argument (obligatorisch):Anzahl der Zeilen
    }
}


%\toggletrue{showComments} % Zum Anzeigen von Kommentaren auf 'true' setzen, zum Ausblenden auf 'false' setzen
\togglefalse{showComments}%zum Verbergen von \mycomment

\toggletrue{showAnswers} % Antworten einblenden
%\togglefalse{showAnswers} % Antworten ausblenden

\begin{document}
    \section{Magnetismus}
    Den wichtigsten Satz als erstes: \\
    
    \begin{large} Es gibt \fillinU{keine magnetischen Monopole!}\end{large}\\
    Das bedeutet:\\
    
    \showTextOrLines[2]{2}{Es gibt keine einzelnen Nord- oder Südpole. Diese können immer nur gemeinsam in einem Magneten auftreten. Entzweit man diesen Magneten, so haben beide neuen wieder einen Nord- und einen Südpol.}
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    Testtest
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

I thought there could be something wrong with the font? But that did not change anything.
Thank for your help

Comment: `\underline` makes a box like `\mbox` so will never linebreak

Comment: I helps, but doesn't work.
Thanks!